# GIT: After git reset --hard HEAD still shows uncommitted changes

Tags: git-reset, git

I git reset hard my local directory:

`git reset --hard HEAD`

But still shows this:

```
git status
On branch step4
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ./

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Any of you knows how can fix this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Untracked files can't be `reset` because they aren't tracked. If you want to delete them (and I really mean *delete*, like from disk) you can do a `git clean -dfx`

Comment: You can't reset a file that isn't tracked.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `git reset` to remove untracked files. This is what `git clean` is for.

`git reset` will only reset the `HEAD` pointer to the commit you specified. The option `--soft` will keep all tracked files as they are while `--hard` reverts them to the state of the commit.

You can clean your working directory with `git clean -f`.

Answer (score 1):

After you `git reset --hard`, you need to run `git clean` in order to remove untracked files. These files are deleted from the drive. If you want to reset your directory **completely**, run `git clean -dfx`. If you want to be more selective, try running `git clean -dfxi` or messing with the parameters as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, the file is not currently tracked. To only remove them from the status display, but not from disk, add the file to your `.gitignore`, e.g.:

```
echo "file.txt" >> .gitignore
```